# Objective-C loop through array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, loops

I have code similar to this

```
if (count == 0)
{
    [array1 addObject:@"No Items"];
} 
else
{
    int x;
    for (x = 0;x <= count; x++) 
    {
            [array1 addObject:[itemsArray objectAtIndex:x];
            NSLog(@"%@",array1);
    }
}
```

`itemsArray` has numbers in it (0-40). My expected result is:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- ...

However it actually does:

- 1
- 1,2
- 1,2,3
- 1,2,3,4
- 1,2,3,4,5
- ...

Why does this happen? If possible, I'd also like to ask for an example to use fast enumeration for this situation (if it suits for this).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: well it might be because you give the NSLog The full array,            NSLog(@"%@",[array1 objectAtIndex:x]); or something like that

Comment: It seems like you could be using `addObjectsFromArray:` instead if looping through itemsArray.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are `NSLog`ing the whole array, not the current index of array1. What you are seeing logged is what you've coded - to log what you are expecting, change `NSLog(@"%@",array1);` to `NSLog(@"%@",[array1 objectAtIndex:x]);`

To confirm add the following after your assignment loop:

```
for (NSObject* o in array1)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",o);
}
```

Comment: Cool! It did worked, indeed I didn't know how to use NSLog properly. I thought fast enumeration could be used substitution for for loops, is it only for logging?

Answer (score 3):

Use   `NSLog(@"%@", [array1 objectATIndex:x]);`

```
if (count == 0)
{
    [array1 addObject:@"No Items"];
} 
else
{
    int x;
    for (x = 0;x <= count; x++) 
    {
            [array1 addObject:[itemsArray objectAtIndex:x];
            NSLog(@"%@", [array1 objectATIndex:x]);
    }
}
```